# У блока не увеличивается высота

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, position

При сжатии блока текст не увеличивает высоту блока, так как блоку с текстом задано `position: absolute`. Я понимаю как это сделать, чтобы работало, если задавать картинку с помощью `background`, но я хочу удобно менять картинку через `html`. Подскажите, возможно, даже какая-то другая разметка, но картинка должна быть в `img`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.post__intro {
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 margin-top: 30px;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 position: relative;
 max-width: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}


.post__intro.first {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 min-height: 470px;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__content {
 position: absolute;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__title {
 font-size: 34px;
 line-height: 1.25;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__img {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
}

.post__intro.first  .post__intro__img:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 background-color: rgba(34, 41, 47, 0.9);
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__text {
 padding: 0 100px;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__info {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.post__intro__info span:not(:last-child)::after {
 content: '·';
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post__intro first">
 <div class="post__intro__img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="post__intro__content">
  <div class="post__intro__title">
   Zero BS CRM 3.0 Improves UI, Changes Database Structure, and Becomes More Extendable
  </div>
  <div class="post__intro__info">
   <span class="post__intro__date">
    7 декабря, 2019
   </span>
   <span class="post__intro__section">
    Новости
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="post__intro__text">
   The team behind Zero BS CRM launched version 3.0 of their WordPress plugin today. This is the first major release … 
  </div>
 </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
</div> <!-- .post__intro.first -->
```

Comment: Сделайте блок с изображением `position:absoulte`, а текст оставьте в потоке.

Comment: @E_K да, точно, получилось